# Handling Model events in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm new to Angularjs and wanting assurance that I'm not implementing an anti-pattern.

I have a `Global controller` that gets a model thru a `factory`. That model supplies data to about a `dozen directives` that sit inside the Global controller's scope.

One of the directives that sits inside the Global controller is a google map and needs to be initialized after I get the lat/long data from the server. I announce the model's arrival using `$rootScope.$broadcast("$site:loaded")` from a `.success()` func in the Global controller, and then I listen for it using `$rootScope.$on("$site:loaded")` in the directive.

Have I implemented an anti-pattern or is this A.O.K.? At first I figured there was already a method I could tap into that would "know" when the model arrived, something like Backbone's `onModelChanged` event.

Any tips about this or about anything else you see in my code? (If it looks good I'll accept answers that say so and explain a little about why it's good, if you can).

Here's the code, starting with the base template:

```
<!-- Global controller implemented as global. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html ng-app="juniper" ng-controller="Global as glb" ng-model="glb.site"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head lang="en-US">
        <base href="/ng-test/">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        {% include "DriverSideSiteBundle:Juniper:stylesheets.html.twig" %}
        {% include "DriverSideSiteBundle:Juniper:javascript.html.twig" %}

        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body vocab="http://schema.org/" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness">
        {#
            These twig files contain <jn-header>
            The scaffolding HTML changes depending on whether the nav is above, below or not
            part of the header
        #}
        {% include 'DriverSideSiteBundle:Juniper:foundation/header.html.twig' with template %}

        <a href="/ng-test/somplace/">create angular 404 page to handle broken links.</a>

        {#
            These twig files contain <jn-sidebar> and <ng-view>
            The scaffolding HTML changes depending on where the nav is and whether there are sidebars
        #}
        {% if template.content.columns == 2 %}
            {% include 'DriverSideSiteBundle:Juniper:foundation/two-column.content.html.twig' with template %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if template.content == 1 %}
            {% include 'DriverSideSiteBundle:Juniper:foundation/one-column.html.twig' with template %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Todo: minify and concatenate into one request. #}
        {% javascripts
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/vendor/angular/angular.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/app.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/site.factory.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/global/global.controller.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/homepage/homepage.controller.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/site-description/site-description.controller.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/site-description/site-description.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/my-garage/my-garage.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/services/services.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/coupons/coupons.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/contact-info/contact-info.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/payments/payments.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/certifications/certifications.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/amenities/amenities.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/jn-map/jn-map.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/jn-nav/jn-nav.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/store-hours/store-hours.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/motorev-admin/motorev-admin.directive.js"
        %}
            {# "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/libs/underscore.module.js" #}          
            {# "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/header/header.directive.js"
            "@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/footer/footer.directive.js" #}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

        {# Depending on the layout, include this or that version of the angular templates during initial request #}
        {% javascripts '@DriverSideSiteBundle/Resources/public/juniper/js/homepage/homepage.html' output='bundles/driversidesite/juniper/homepage/homepage.html'%}
      {% endjavascripts %}
        {% block angularTemplates %}
        {% endblock %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Trigger foundation's js
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).foundation();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Replace key with dynamic key -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyEYqzoex1QGMLK1YXDye8vIs0o-lQbLQ">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The `Site` factory is injected into the Global controller which calls the Site's `getSite(:siteId)` method. This method makes an $http request. The returned data is set to the `Site` factory; I saw that practice somewhere and thought it looked good.

```
/**
 *  global.controller.js
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var juniper = angular.module('juniper');

    juniper.controller('Global', [ '$rootScope', 'Site', function($rootScope, Site){
        var self = this;

        // Assign the site model to this controller's `site` attr
        this.site = Site;
        // Use the site model's get method to retrieve the site info
        var promise = this.site.getSite(1409); // Todo: Include the Id dynamically


        promise
            .success( $.proxy(function(data, status, headers, config){
                // Bind to the Site obj
                angular.extend(this, data.data);

                // Broadcast when the data arrives so that other directives and controllers can do something when it arrives 
                $rootScope.$broadcast("$site:loaded");

            }, Site)) // Pass in the Site object for the data to bind to
            .error( function(data, status, headers, config) {
                var error = 'error';
                error += '/n data: ' + data;
                error += '/n status: ' + status;
                error += '/n headers: ' + headers;
                error += '/n config: ' + config;

                console.log(error); // Log error
            });
    }]);

}());
```

The `Site factory` has a Site object that holds the getter and setter functions as well as all the data returned from the server:

```
/**
 *  site.factory.js
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var juniper = angular.module('juniper');

    juniper.factory('Site', function($http){

        /**
         *  Site obj is passed to whichever controller needs the site model.
         *  The site obj contains all the methods for getting/setting data as well
         *  as the data itself.
         *
         *  In this case, the site obj is set to the global controller which passes
         *  a reference thru inheritance to all other controllers.
         */
        var Site = {

            /**
             *  Get the site
             *  siteId (int) is the integer id of the site to be retrieved
             */
            getSite: function(siteId) {

                var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/site/' + siteId;

                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url
                });
            }
        };

        // Return the site obj.
        // You'll need to call the site obj methods once assigning it to a controller's attr.
        return Site;

    });

}());
```

So that's the Global controller which contains the model fetched by the Site factory. Here's the map directive and map template:

```
<!-- I didn't specify an ng-model. I didn't see a reason to insert an ng-model since the map directive uses data from the Global controller and nothing else. Is there a way for me to specify that this directive's model is just a portion of the Global model, like by glb.site.location here or by setting the `scope` in the directive declaration ...? Is there a value to doing either of these? -->
<!-- Also didn't specify an ng-controller because I could stick the functions handling this directive's UI in the directive's link function. Is this smart practice, bad practice, or just "a practice"? -->
<div class="Pod">
  <h3 class="Pod__Head show-for-small-only">Location</h3>
  <div class="Pod__Body">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The map directive. Notice that I listen for the $scope.$broadcast which comes from the Global controller. I also set `scope:false` which gives it the Global controller's scope:

```
/**
 *  jn-map.directives.js
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Create template-path variable for easy maintenance
    var path = '/bundles/driversidesite/juniper/';

    var juniper = angular.module('juniper');

    juniper.directive("jnMap", function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: false, // Tell where to transclude the element using the ng-transclude attr
        templateUrl: path + 'jn-map/jn-map.html',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {

            $rootScope.$on("$site:loaded", $.proxy(function(){
                var mapOptions = {
                  center: {
                    lat: parseFloat(this.site.locations[0].latitude),
                    lng: parseFloat(this.site.locations[0].longitude)
                  },
                  zoom: 8
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
            }, scope.glb)); // Pass in the Global controller's model
        }
      }
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed looks like an anti-pattern to me. I would simply only add the map directive to the DOM once the site is available.

In the controller:

```
promise.success(function(data) {
    $scope.loadedSite = data;
}
```

In the template:

```
<jn-map site="loadedSite" ng-if="loadedSite"></jn-map>
```

The directive would have a scope containing the site, and would only ever be called once the site is loaded thanks to the `ng-if`:

```
juniper.directive("jnMap", function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: path + 'jn-map/jn-map.html',
    scope: {
      site: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: {
                lat: parseFloat(scope.site.locations[0].latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(scope.site.locations[0].longitude)
              },
              zoom: 8
            };
            new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
          }
  };
});
```

Note that this directive displays the map in the directive's element, and not in another, unrelated element. `element` is a jQuery-like element wrapper object, and `element[0]` is thus the raw DOM element.

Comment: So first you create a property in the `Global controller`'s scope called `loadedSite.` This is created when the $site obj arrives from server. Then you've added a `site` property to `jn-map directive` which is set to `loadedSite.` (The `ng-if` portion is straightforward). Then in my `jn-map` directive you set the `site` property to operate on two-way binding (`"="`), which makes it available in the link function. Have I got it right? ...Must I bind `loadedSite` to `$scope` or can I bind it to `this`? (I've tried so far but failed). And is it not as good to set `scope:false`?

Comment: (btw, your solution works and I plan to accept it as soon as I understand it better, so thanks!)

Comment: One reason I ask about binding `loadedSite` to `this` rather than `$scope` is that I like to use the `Controller as...` syntax. In order for my model properties to be printed to other parts of the page while using your answer I find that I need to bind `data` both to `this` and to `$scope`. That seems wonky though.